# swift-WKWebView: A black WKCompositingView is above my WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview

when I use WKWebView, I encountered a problem .

When I  ->  webView.GoBack,
sometimes there is a black WKCompositingView is above my WKWebView,I don't know why? And Sometimes touch GoBack more times , a black WKCompositingView can disappear.

So I can't operate my wkWebView screen

Does anyone know the solution?
thanks...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYM8o.png)